# Android: Getting all existing exif data from an image

Tags: android, exif

I know it's possible to get specific exif data by specifying the string tag in the ExifInterface. For example, getting the date of an image would be something like:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(pathToImage);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
```

Is there a way to simply get all of the non-null available exif strings without having to manually write the get code for each of them?

Comment: Android was, is, and most probably will always be the most dumbest of OSes ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make an array of all tags that you wish to query, and put the non-null results of the query into a collection (maybe hashmap) or something else (maybe JsonObject).

Example in Kotlin:

```
    val pathToImage = "..."
    val exif = ExifInterface(pathToImage)
    val tagsToCheck = arrayOf(
        ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE,
        ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME
    )
    val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
    for (tag in tagsToCheck)
        exif.getAttribute(tag)?.let { hashMap[tag] = it }
```

Comment: is this the only way?

Comment: @PandiriDeepak Well you could use reflection instead of creating an array of the tags you wish to query. It's more automatic, but less safe.

Comment: @androiddeveloper how do you do this with kotlin for example ?

Comment: @micaball Added sample.