# Android: How to check which camera was used to capture an image

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Is there a way to figure out whether the front camera or the back camera was used to capture an image? If so, how can I get that information using the built-in Camera app?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first, where you must find this information? Directly in android or on a server on you have uploaded the image?

1. On server you can use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to read the value of **Camera Identifier** in this way:

   ```
   bin_path/exiftool <imagePath> | grep -E 'Camera Identifier'
   ```
2. Directly in android you can try to do the same and can find usefull start code here [Getting all existing exif data from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954046/android-getting-all-existing-exif-data-from-an-image)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Read image metadata, maybe there will be something useful.